# Protractor - Compare two elements having same locator

Tags: protractor

My application uses infinite scrolling on row of records which means a locator for any particular record, say last record, is always going to be same but the record underneath is going to be different every time I do a scroll.

I wish to compare the the element corresponding to last element before it is scrolled to the same element corresponding to last element after it is scrolled

Protractor has a function 'equals' but I suppose it compares based on the locator which is why it always result as true when I compare the last elements having same locator but different record.

Is there any other way to compare two elements directly?

Answer (score 1):

Its very simlple. before you perform scrolling store the text in some variable. After performing scrolling again use the same locator to get the latest record's text. Look at below example code.

```
var textOfLastRecordBeforescrolling = element.all(by.css("someLocator")).last().getText();
//Perform Scrolling
var textOfLastRecordAfterscrolling = element.all(by.css("someLocator")).last().getText();
expect(textOfLastRecordBeforescrolling).toEqual(textOfLastRecordAfterscrolling) //do whatever comparison you want do
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to save the information from the first element, then scroll, get the information from the second, and then compare.

```js
  it('Has different elements after infinite scrolling', function(){
    var elementOfInterest = $$('.infiniteScrollElement').last();

    // Get the text of the first element and pass it down
    elementOfInterest.getText().then(function(firstElementsText){
      // Scroll however far you need to
      browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,500);').then(function(){
        // Compare the current elements text with the past elements text
        expect(elementOfInterest.getText()).not.toEqual(firstElementsText, 'Error: The text should be different between the two elements, but was not');
      })
    })
  });
```

Comment: Is it not possible to compare the element object directly instead of reading text?

Comment: @Manya What would you like to do with it? A protractor web element just contains a few static things like its selector and a list of functions that can be performed, but those all resolve into promises which are done when called. The result of its functions are usually useful, not generally the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

To compare an instance of a web element, you can test the value returned by `element(...).getId()`.

The returned id is a reference generated for each encounter `HTMLElement` object in the page and is not related to the id attribute/property.

This is an example to scroll the content and wait for the last element to be replaced:

```js
browser.get("https://twitter.com/BBC/");

// define the locator for the last element
var lastElement = $$('#stream-items-id > li').last();

// store the reference for the last element
var storedRef = lastElement.getId();

// scroll to the last element
browser.actions().mouseMove(lastElement).perform();

// wait for the last element to be another reference
browser.wait(function(){
  return storedRef.then(function(a){
      return lastElement.getId().then(b => a !== b);
  }, 3000);
});

// compare the stored reference with the last element
expect(lastElement.getId()).not.toEqual(storedRef);
```

Comment: This solutions looks good. Only downside is that I cannot compare the 'ids' using === operator. I have to use localeCompare for that

Comment: @Manya, the execution is asynchronous, so it's not possible to compare two elements directly with an equality operator. It has to go through the resolution of a promise.